# GWT "viewport" scrolling for mobile screen

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt application which is developed to be also used with mobile.
I have this tag put in the html file of the gwt app to fit the app in mobile screen:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

However I need to allow the app to be scrolled vertically, as the app will output a list results. I have tried to wrap the main VerticalPanel with ScrollPanel however it still does not scroll vertically?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you give a fixed size to your scroll panel? Otherwise it automatically grows to fit its content.

Comment: I didn't give the scroll panel a fixed size, the VerticalPanel that it wraps height & width is set to Window.getClientWidth and Window.getClientHeight through a ResizeHandler to center the widget in the browser screen.

Comment: I dont know how mobile enviroment affects the behaviour of scroll panel. But to get vertical scrolling, you need to give a smaller height to your ScrollPanel than what you wrap (VerticalPanel in your case) to actually get the scrollbars. When you set no size on your ScrollPanel, it automatically becomes as big as what it wraps so you don't get any scroll bars.